# Installation Error In Bootstrap?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, therubyracer

I am working on windows.

Installed `gem twitter-bootstrap-rails -v 2.2.8`
`gem less`
.
Then also error in the `gem the rubyracer`

Tried:
I have also tried `therubyracer for_windows`
I am using `rails 4.0.0`.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT YOUR GEM FILE WITH:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'libv8'
```

Note: Install python to install libv8.